# Elegant function definition in C++

Tags: c++, function, macros

I have the following functions:

```
void func1(int8_t input);
void func1(int16_t input);
void func1(int32_t input);
void func1(float input);
```

The implementation of the four functions is the same, except for some internal value that are in accordance with the input type (`int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t` or `float`).

Currently I am creating the other three functions by copy-paste but this is quite tedious.

Is there any way so that I only write 1 function (for example, `func1(int8_t input);`) and that at building time, the other three functions are created automatically?

Or in which this could work with no need of the other three functions? Any other solution is well appreciated.

Comment: You cannot have four same function names with different argument types, not in C.

Comment: You can't have those four functions in C - it doesn't support overloading, so you'll have to give them different names (eg func1_int8). They can have the same name in C++, but that language has better mechanisms (eg templates) for achieving what you want than C does.

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: What's stopping you from using templates for this? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template

Comment: I was going to suggest a template, assuming the logic inside each function is basically the same.  And I'm not sure why this is marked down.  It's a perfectly reasonable question, the answer to which is to learn about templates.

Comment: @Robinson if you look at the history of this the OP marked the question initially as a `c` question, someone spent time answering this as a `c` question, it then transmogrified into a `c++` question so presumably some people are unhappy at this sudden genus change

Comment: Ok.  I missed that.

Comment: OP mis-categorized this as C and not C++, a simple mistake that was corrected. I don't think the downvotes were necessary, the question is valid for C++

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about templates. I am reading about it and it is just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usage of template function is the solution for this problem:

```
template <typename T>
void func1(const T value)
{
   //   Do some stuff
}
```

If you need to use special internal  value, which depends on input type, you can use auxiliary type traits like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct SomeTrait
{
   static const int value = 10;
};

template <>
struct SomeTrait<float>
{
   static const int value = 20;
};

template <typename T>
void func1(const T value)
{
   std::cout << SomeTrait<T>::value << std::endl;
   //   Do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly needing a template function. This will require C++11

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T
          // This constrains the template function instantiation to only
          // integral and floating types
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value
                                             ||
                                             std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
void func1(T input)
{
  ......
  T tmp; // Use the same data type inside function
}
```

If you want to keep it simple and w/o C++11, then just do

```
template <typename T>
void func1(T input)
{
  ......
  T tmp; // Use the same data type inside function
}
```

The disadvantage is that you cannot constrain the instantiation of this function template only to integral and floating types. You can use boost::enable_if and other type traits instead of 'std::enable_if' and std:: type_traits in this case though.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it as a template function:

```
template<typename T> void func1(T input) {
    // ...
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
float f = 1.234;
func1<float>(f);

int32_t i32 = 45678;
func1<int32_t>(i32);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates if the implementation of the functions are equal:

```
template <typename T>
void func1(const T value)
{
   //   Do some stuff
}
```

If the implementation is different for some input type you can specify this specialization, e.g.

```
void func1(const complex value)
{
   //   Do some stuff related to complex values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using template function.

```
template <typename T>
void your_function(const T input){

 // do something

}
```

in the other hand, you can specify your template function

```
template <>
void your_function(const float input){


// do some specific things

}
```